# PHP Parsing String of HTML

Tags: php, html, string, parsing

thanks for taking a second to look at this. I'm using a PHP script to get the source code of a page from a URL, and then I am attempting to parse it and display a certain part text. The problem appears to be that when I get the source for the link (with:

```
$data = file_get_contents($link);
```

) the variable $data stores it as HTML and not as just a string. I'm pretty new to PHP so I'm not 10% sure if that's the case, but I do know that if I try to display $data in any way it displays not as plain text but as HTML with HTML formatting.

Ordinarily this wouldn't be an issue but I am trying to get the value of something inside an HTML tag, like this:

```
$search = strpos($data, $searchterm);
```

and because it is either stored as HTML instead of as plain text or it is treated that way, strpos() will only search through the text that would be displayed if I loaded the page.

To be more specific, in my file (YouTube data about my account) it would only look at what would display if it were to be loaded as HTML, which is pure nonsense.

Here is the source that I want it to search through (I have replaced my account name with 'MyAccount' for privacy):

```
<entry gd:etag="W/"A0MFR347eCp7I2A9WhNQEU4."" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<id>tag:youtube.com,2008:user:A1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlg</id>
<published>2007-01-23T15:39:30.000Z</published>
<updated>2012-11-17T08:03:36.000Z</updated>
<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#userProfile"/>
<title>MyAccount</title>
<summary/>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlg"/>
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/A1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlg?v=2"/>
<author>
<name>MyAccount</name>
<uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount</uri>
<yt:userId>A1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlg</yt:userId>
</author>
<yt:channelId>UCA1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlg</yt:channelId>
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.liveevent" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount/live/events?v=2" countHint="0"/>
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.favorites" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount/favorites?v=2" countHint="0"/>
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.contacts" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount/contacts?v=2" countHint="71"/>
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.inbox" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount/inbox?v=2"/>
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.playlists" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount/playlists?v=2"/>
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.subscriptions" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount/subscriptions?v=2" countHint="54"/>
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount/uploads?v=2" countHint="41"/>
<gd:feedLink rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.newsubscriptionvideos" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccount/newsubscriptionvideos?v=2"/>
<yt:location>US</yt:location>
<yt:maxUploadDuration seconds="43200"/>
<yt:statistics lastWebAccess="2012-07-08T15:58:07.000Z" subscriberCount="126" videoWatchCount="0" viewCount="3385" totalUploadViews="50179"/>
<media:thumbnail url="http://i2.ytimg.com/i/A1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlg/1.jpg?v=934f35"/>
<yt:userId>A1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlg</yt:userId>
<yt:username display="MyAccount">MyAccount</yt:username>
</entry>
```

And here is what it searches through/has access to:

```
tag:youtube.com,2008:user:A1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlg2007-01-23T15:39:30.000Z2012-11-17T08:03:36.000Z
MyAccounthttp://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MyAccountA1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlgUCA1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlgUSA1RDBCYeYWY9dydB9MmPlgMyAccount
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: One word, three letters: [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: How many times do we have to repeat this? **Do not parse HTML/XML as text.**

Comment: try : $search = strpos($data, '<title>');  or try preg_match with patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
    $data = file_get_contents($link);
    $searchterm = ''; //as necessary

    $data = strtr($data,Array("<"=>"&lt;","&"=>"&amp;"));
    $searchterm = strtr($searchterm,Array("<"=>"&lt;","&"=>"&amp;"));

    $search = strpos($data, $searchterm);
```

The middle lines makes HTML readable for PHP to process

Comment: This works great to make it display the whole source when I try 
echo($data);
However it will still not let strpos(); search the whole thing, any ideas?

Comment: Did you try my edit with a line that processes $searchterm?
This is necessary as &lt; will be compared with < and will fail.

Comment: Just tried the edit, it works perfectly!! Thanks a ton for helping out a newbie! :D